# Twisted deferred.callback(value) fires callback with None

Tags: twisted

Writing a unit test for a twisted application. Trying to perform some asserts once deferred is resolved with a new(dummy) connection (instance of `proto_helpers.StringTransport`), however callback `assert_cache_updated_on_connection` is receiving `None` instead of the `connection` that was passed to `<deferred>.callback(connection)`

```
def test_send_to_new_connection(self):
    # Given
    peerAddr = ('10.22.22.190', 5060)

    # If
    self.tcp_transport.send_to('test', peerAddr)

    # Then
    assert peerAddr in self.tcp_transport._connections
    assert True == isinstance(self.tcp_transport._connections[peerAddr], Deferred)

    connection = _string_transport_connection(self.hostAddr, peerAddr, None, self.tcp_transport.connectionMade)

    def assert_cache_updated_on_connection(connection):
        print('--------- SUCCESS ----------')
        peer = connection.transport.getPeer()
        peerAddr = (peer.host, peer.port)

        assert peerAddr in self.tcp_transport._connections
        assert True == isinstance(self.tcp_transport._connections[peerAddr], Protocol)

    def assert_fail(fail):
        print('--------- FAIL ----------')

    self.tcp_transport._connections[peerAddr].addCallback(assert_cache_updated_on_connection)
    self.tcp_transport._connections[peerAddr].addErrback(assert_fail)
    # Forcing deferred to fire with mock connection
    self.tcp_transport._connections[peerAddr].callback(connection)
```

Is this the right way to manually fire deferred callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A callback receives as its first argument one of two things:

- If it is the first callback, it receives the value passed to the `callback` method.
- If it is a subsequent callback, it receives the return value of the callback before it.

So presumably the explanation is that `assert_cache_updated_on_connection` is not the first callback and that the callback before it is returning `None`.